# Centos 7 IPV6 "Crash"

Tags: centos7, ipv6

I am not entirely sure where I would start to debug this and am really hoping someone could point me in the right direction, please. I have spent a lot of time searching around, but given that things seem to work for a few hours/days this hasn't really proved fruitful.

But in a nutshell IPV6 seems to work fine on my Centos 7 system for a limited time, as per the ping6 log:

```
PING ipv6.google.com(par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=0.830 ms
64 bytes from par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=0.863 ms
64 bytes from par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=0.856 ms

--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.830/0.849/0.863/0.036 ms
```

Then for some reason after a few hours or a few days no matter what I try I can't get IPv6 to work, until I do a machine reboot from the terminal (using the "reboot" command) and then it all works again for a limited amount of time, then the process needs to be repeated.

The original guide I used from my host to setup IPv6 is here (https://documentation.online.net/en/dedicated-server/network/ipv6/prefix) - ignore the Dibbler warning as I don't use this. As it happens I did before and I can attest to it working for an even shorter time than the current solution.

My machines details are as follows;

```
         Icon name: computer
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Hopefully, someone has had this problem themselves and can advise on a better solution that doesn't involve me setting up a cron to reboot the system each day?

***Editing original post to add on extra information:***

I am not aware of any firewall restrictions (unless there is something specific to IPv6), however, as a part of trying to solve this, I have disabled IP Tables and the Centos firewalld to try and rule them out. They were enabled for the information provided below.

**The routing information I am aware of:**

*First when it isn't working.*

```
root > ping6 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e)) 56 data bytes
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms



root > route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway             Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         62-210-***-***.rev  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
62.210.***.0    0.0.0.0             255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0



root > route -6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
[::]/96                        [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
0.0.0.0/96                     [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
<MY HOSTNAME>/56               [::]                       U    256 0     0 eth0
2002:a00::/24                  [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:7f00::/24                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:a9fe::/32                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:ac10::/28                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:c0a8::/32                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:e000::/19                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
3ffe:ffff::/32                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
gateway/128                    [::]                       U    100 0     2 eth0
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 1    47 eth0
[::]/0                         gateway                    UG   100 1    23 eth0
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1    81 lo
localhost/128                  [::]                       Un   0   9  1157 lo
<MY HOSTNAME>/128              [::]                       Un   0   5     8 lo
<MY HOSTNAME>/128              [::]                       Un   0   2     8 lo
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 5   224 eth0
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 0     0 eth1
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1    81 lo



root > ip route
default via 62.210.***.*** dev eth0 proto static metric 100
62.210.***.***/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 62.210.***.*** metric 100
```

**Now when it is working (the only difference between the two is that I have rebooted the server)**

```
root > ping6 ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=0.808 ms
64 bytes from par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=0.863 ms
64 bytes from par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=0.867 ms
64 bytes from par21s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:812::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=0.869 ms
?
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.808/0.851/0.869/0.043 ms



root > route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway             Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         62-210-***-***.rev  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
62.210.***.0    0.0.0.0             255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0



root > route -6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
[::]/96                        [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
0.0.0.0/96                     [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
<MY HOSTNAME>/56 [::]                       U    256 0     0 eth0
2002:a00::/24                  [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:7f00::/24                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:a9fe::/32                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:ac10::/28                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:c0a8::/32                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
2002:e000::/19                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
3ffe:ffff::/32                 [::]                       !n   1024 0     0 lo
gateway/128                    [::]                       U    100 0    10 eth0
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 0     4 eth0
[::]/0                         gateway                    UG   100 11   752 eth0
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1   777 lo
localhost/128                  [::]                       Un   0   13 15498 lo
<MY HOSTNAME>/128 [::]                       Un   0   13   241 lo
<MY HOSTNAME>/128 [::]                       Un   0   4    12 lo
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 10  2254 eth0
ff00::/8                       [::]                       U    256 0     0 eth1
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1   777 lo



root > ip route
default via 62.210.***.*** dev eth0 proto static metric 100
62.210.***.***/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 62.210.***.*** metric 100
```

**Now the applicable config files**

*/etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf*

```
interface "eth0" {
   send dhcp6.client-id <MY DUID - This was provided by the host>;
}
```

*/etc/systemd/system/dhclient.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=dhclient for sending DUID IPv6
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhclient -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf -6 -P -v eth0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0*

```
# Generated by parse-kickstart
UUID="2688a41f-e07a-****-****-************"
DNS1="62.210.***.***"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR="62.210.***.***"
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY="62.210.***.***"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6ADDR="2001:bc8:****:***::/56" 
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
NAME="System eth0"
```

Comment: ` I can't get IPv6 to work` this is not at all useful. What exactly does that mean. have you looked in your logs and are there any relevant messages.

Comment: Hello @user430214, that was part of my question. I am not sure where this is logged or where I would begin to start understanding the problem.

It's not so much that I can't get it to work. It's more that I can't get it to work reliably.

Comment: By `I can't get IPv6 to work` I mean restarting all the services I think would be relevant, ensuring the config files are correct, looking through all the log files I know exist.

By doing this I haven't managed to find a problem.

Comment: Please show your interface configuration. Also show your IPv6 addresses and routing table both when it is working and when it isn't. If you have an IPv6 firewall configured please show that as well.

Comment: Hi Sander, thank you for taking the time to try and assist me, I really appreciate it. I have included as much information as I know how to provide in an edit to the original post. Please excuse my ignorance or lack of knowledge on this subject as it has really taken me out of my "comfort zone" when it comes to server management.

Comment: The neighbor table is probably relevant. What does `ip -6 neigh` say?

Comment: Working
`fe80::c28c:60ff:fee1:ca7 dev eth0 lladdr c0:8c:60:e1:0c:a7 router REACHABLE`

Not working
`fe80::c28c:60ff:fee1:ca7 dev eth0 lladdr c0:8c:60:e1:0c:a7 router STALE`

Comment: @DavidThompson In that case the neighbor table is definitely relevant. Your router is not `REACHABLE`. At this point you need to look at ICMPv6 traffic on the interface. Maybe somebody did something silly like configuring a firewall to drop ICMPv6 packets. Try `tcpdump -pni eth0 -s0 -Uw icmpv6.pcap icmp6` right after boot and leave it running until the problem shows up and then open the file in Wireshark to see what changed when the problem started.